# woocommerce auto change role based on order amount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, roles

I am trying to get my code to change the users role based on if the user have 10 or more orders that is in processing/completed. It checks the buyers email to match it with other orders. When trying to place new order i get internal server error, i have tryed servral solutions without any luck.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'change_user_role_based_on_order_count', 10, 1);

function change_user_role_based_on_order_count($order_id) {
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    // Get the user email associated with the order
    $user_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    
    // Exclude administrators from role change
    if (email_exists($user_email) && user_can(email_exists($user_email), 'administrator')) {
        return; // Exit the function
    }
    
    // Get the user ID associated with the order email
    $user_id = email_exists($user_email);
    
    // Get the user's current role
    $current_user_role = get_user_role($user_id);
    
    // Define the desired role
    $desired_role = 'your_desired_role';
    
    // Check if the user has more than 10 orders and is not already in the desired role
    if (get_user_order_count($user_id) > 10 && $current_user_role !== $desired_role) {
        // Update the user's role to the desired role
        wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $desired_role));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the  `get_user_order_count(..`  function refer to in your code? 
you call a function, but the function is nowhere mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in the code:

1. a `WP_User` should be passed to `user_can()` function
2. `get_customer_order_count()` should be `wc_get_customer_order_count()`
3. setting user's role using `$user->set_role( $desired_role );`

   ```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'change_user_role_based_on_order_count', 10, 2 );
   function change_user_role_based_on_order_count( $order_id, $order ) {
      $user_email = $order->get_billing_email();
      $user       = get_user_by( 'email', $user_email );
      if ( ! $user ) {
         return;
      }
      if ( user_can( $user, 'manage_options' ) ) {
         return;
      }
      // Get the user's current roles.
      $user_roles = $user->roles;

      // Define the desired role
      $desired_role = 'your_desired_role';

      // Check if the user has more than 10 orders and is not already in the desired role
      if ( wc_get_customer_order_count( $user->ID ) > 10 && ! in_array( $desired_role, $user_roles ) ) {
          // Either add a new role using `add_role()` or overwrite user roles by using `set_role()`
          $user->set_role( $desired_role ); // $user->add_role( $desired_role );
       }}
   ```

Comment: how do i make it check if the orders are in processing and completed only?'

Comment: You can use a late hook like 'woocommerce_payment_complete' hook. This hook passes the order ID and transaction ID, so all you need to add is "$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); in the function.